# launch an external program C# button, and function in this program

Tags: c#

Im trying to make aprogram that has a connection to databas om mysql.
I want that when the user click on a button the server will run, and Apatche and Mysql will even run.

here my code to run Xamp,  But how to run Apatche and Mysql in it  ?

```
  private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process c = new Process();
        c.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe";
        c.Start();
        //Start apatchi

    }
```

here pic of the program and the functions i wanna run

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41be5cac-9fd1-40cf-bcf8-d0f2f3223915/how-to-start-apache22-on-usb-stick-service-using-c?forum=netfxbcl) might help you!!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running `xampp` there is an easier solution. `Xampp` usually comes packaged with a few `.bat` file that when run do exactly what you want. For example `mysql_start.bat` when run will only start MySql server and nothing else, while `mysql_stop.bat` will stop it (and nothing else). There is also a `apache_start.bat` and a `apache_stop.bat`.

You can execute these scripts just as you would an exe:

```
Process c = new Process();
        c.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\xampp\mysql_start.bat";
        c.Start();
```